# Having trouble assigning a string variable to a structure member

Tags: c++

I have a function called "modifyRecord" that is supposed to get input for the record number and new Product values, seek to that record number, and write the new values to replace the existing data. The problem I'm having is that I need to get the product name and can't figure out how to do it.

I created a temporary structure variable called "prod" to store the input from the file and a string variable "str" to save the product name to. I need to use the input from a .dat file, edit the info, save it to the structure, and then write that new info to the file.

The problem is that I am using strcpy to save 'str' to 'prod.name.' I think I understand why this is wrong, but I don't know what else to do.

Here are the function (if you need more code, let me know and I'll edit it):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

const int NAME_SIZE = 40;

struct Product
{
    long number;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    double price;
    int quantity;
};

void modifyRecord(fstream&);

int main() {

    fstream inventoryFile;
    inventoryFile.open("inventory.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);

    if (inventoryFile) {
        createFile(inventoryFile);
        cout << "Inventory File created.\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: Cannot open file." << endl;
    }
    
    modifyRecord(inventoryFile);

    inventoryFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void createFile(fstream& inventoryFile) {
    
    Product milk;
    milk.number = 15478;
    strcpy(milk.name, "Whole Milk");
    milk.price = 2.99;
    milk.quantity = 30;
    inventoryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&milk), sizeof(milk));
}

void modifyingRecord(fstream& inventoryFile) {

    inventoryFile.seekg(0);

    string str;

    inventoryFile.clear();

    int tempNum = 0;
    Product prod;

    cout << "\nEnter Record Number: ";
    cin >> tempNum;

    inventoryFile.seekg(tempNum, ios::beg);

    cout << "Enter New Product Number: \n";
    cin >> prod.number;

    cout << "\nEnter New Product Name: \n";
    getline(cin, str);
    cin.ignore();
    strcpy(prod.name, str);

    cout << "\nEnter New Price: \n";
    cin >> prod.price;
    cout << "\nEnter New Quantity: ";
    cin >> prod.quantity;

    inventoryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prod), sizeof(Product));
    
}
```

I tried changing the datatype from 'string' to 'const char,' but that messed up at the getline function two lines above it. I also tried assigning 'prod.name' directly to str, but that didn't work either. The structure member 'name' is a char datatype.

Comment: Try `strcpy(prod.name, str.c_str());`. Also, your `seekg` call seems wrong - shouldn't that go to `tempNum * sizeof(Product)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Without knowing what, e.g. `prod.name` is or what your `.dat` files is (generally binary), we're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the help on the strcpy function. I think that should work. As for seekg, I'm still learning some of the more advanced stuff for file operations, so I might have that wrong. Should it be written as inventoryFileseekg(temp, sizeOf(Product))? I had it written as (tempNum, ios::beg) to have it start searching at the beginning of the file. Did I write that wrong?

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thanks for the response! Sorry, I'm still pretty new. I'll definitely check those links out and try to post better, next time. I'll also add some code above so I'll run.

Comment: Basically a MCRE is your minimum code that shows the problem that we can copy/paste/compile and reproduce your results with (also so we can enlist the aid of a debugger to isolate any issues not immediately apparent) Here we would also need a `.dat` file with a couple of products in it so we can see how you are reading and writing the data.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code above. Hopefully, that'll run well enough to see the problem I'm running into.

Comment: Order is important. In most cases C++ reads top down, and `createFile` is requested before the compiler's told that it exists

Comment: No guarantees that `strcpy` is defined by any of the headers used. It will be defined in string.h. Whups. There's me going all C again. `strcpy` will be in cstring.

Comment: Adrian picked off the other mistake that jumps out at me. Clean up those and you'll have compiling code. Then you'll get the logic error Adrian picked off.

Comment: You are trying to do too many new things at once. When you first try to implement something, implement it *in isolation* as mush as possible. Don't try to incorporate it into a larger program until it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems and does not even compile yet. Anyway the reason for error is in the consumption of the input data. When you read a number you must then read whatever is left on the buffer, at least the `\n` that ended the `cin` operation.

### About the code

This is `C` code. And there is no reason to use C++ this way.

Anyway:

- there is a prototype for `modifyRecord()` but the funcion in the code is `modifyingRecord()`.
- One way of making this code work is to insert calls to `ignore()` on `cin` to consume the rest of the data after reading numbers, since the rest will stay there. The program has no way of deciding what to do if you eventually type `42 US dollars` as price.
- the call to `strcpy()` must extract the `C string` from `str` as in

```
       strcpy(prod.name, str.c_str());
```

and not

```
strcpy(prod.name, str);
```

since `str` in itself is not `char*`

- The prototype for `CreateFile()` is missing

#### More about the code

- I see that this is just a test, but it works only for the first record in file. Why not do the simple and pass the record number as a `const`?
- You do not show the data before writing and do not show the data after changing the values, so it is a bit hard to know if the program is working
- code for reading data and changing files is mixed in a single function. These is not good. Never write interactive good still you can not to.
- use a C++ `struct`. It is way more simple. Or just use `C`.

#### an example

This way the code should work, but it is not a good one. I am just trying to show how to correct the first problems in the code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

const int NAME_SIZE = 40;

struct Product
{
    long   number;
    char   name[NAME_SIZE];
    double price;
    int    quantity;
};

void createFile(fstream&);
void modifyingRecord(fstream&);

int main(void)
{
    fstream inventoryFile;
    inventoryFile.open(
        "inventory.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::in);

    if (inventoryFile)
    {
        createFile(inventoryFile);
        cout << "Inventory File created.\n";
    }
    else { cout << "Error: Cannot open file." << endl; }

    modifyingRecord(inventoryFile);

    inventoryFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void createFile(fstream& inventoryFile)
{
    Product milk;
    milk.number = 15478;
    strcpy(milk.name, "Whole Milk");
    milk.price    = 2.99;
    milk.quantity = 30;
    inventoryFile.write(
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(&milk), sizeof(milk));
}

void modifyingRecord(fstream& inventoryFile)
{
    inventoryFile.seekg(0);

    string str;

    inventoryFile.clear();

    int     tempNum = 0;
    Product prod;

    cout << "\nEnter Record Number: ";
    cin >> tempNum;

    inventoryFile.seekg(tempNum, ios::beg);

    cout << "Enter New Product Number: \n";
    cin >> prod.number;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "\nEnter New Product Name: \n";
    getline(cin, str);
    strcpy(prod.name, str.c_str());

    cout << "\nEnter New Price: \n";
    cin >> prod.price;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "\nEnter New Quantity: ";
    cin >> prod.quantity;
    cin.ignore();

    inventoryFile.write(
        reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prod), sizeof(Product));
}
```